# (Full) Solution to $\int \frac{1-x}{x^2+x+1}dx$ with steps.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

1. If we use substitution, we get:

$u=x^2+x+1$

$du=(2x+1)dx$

$(-1/2)du=(-x-1/2)dx=(-x+1-3/2)dx$

2. Then the integral becomes:

$\int ((-du/2)/u) + 3/2\int dx/(x^2+x+1$)

But why isn't it just:
$\int ((-1/2du)-3/2)/u$ ?

And why do you use + 3/2 in the original answer and not -3/2, if -1/2du = (-x+1-3/2)dx ? I don't really understand step 2.

---

Edit: Please post a full solution to the question in the title: $\displaystyle \int \frac{1-x}{x^2+x+1}dx$ with all the steps.

Comment: Please edit your text. You can use LaTeX/Mathjax to typeset your equation. Look at my edits and you will see how it works.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have $du$ in just one part of the integral. What does $\int (3/2)/u$ on its own (without $du$) even *mean*? You should instead complete the square to get $(1-x)/((x+\frac12)^2+\frac34)$ and use the substitution $u=x+\frac12$.

Comment: Could you post an answer of the full solution to the question in the title with all the steps? $\int \dfrac{1-x}{x^2+x+1}dx$ . I don't really understand this answer as well

Comment: @MrYouMath I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \int\frac{1-x}{x^2+x+1}dx=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{dx}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}dx$.

Let $\displaystyle x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan\theta$. Then $\displaystyle dx=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^2\theta d\theta$ and $\displaystyle \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{4}\sec^2\theta$. So,

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int d\theta=\theta+C=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$.

Comment: Why equals 3/2? And could you use more steps so it is easier to understand?

Comment: $1-x=\frac{3-(2x+1)}{2}$

Comment: And how do you get from 1-x to (3-(2x+1))/2 ? I have difficulty in understanding the first steps.

Comment: $\int\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}dx$ is easy to integrate. So obtaining $2x+1$ is the target. If $1-x=a+b(2x+1)$, then $a+b=1$ and $2b=-1$.